# Receiving build failed error "Use of undeclared identifier 'ParseClientConfiguration'"

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, xcode8

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPoP2.png)

Long time lurker, first time posting. I am attempting migrate my parse.com db to back4app. The migration has gone flawlessly, but now I'm running into trouble changing where the app points to access the parse server. The code I am using came straight from back4app's guides [here](http://docs.back4app.com/docs/parse-migration/parse-sdk/how-to-update-parse-sdk-for-ios/).

I am running Xcode 8.0, and the app is designed for a minimum of iOS 9. I am using cocoa pods to manage parse as well as several others, so I have the latest version of cocoa pods (1.1.1) and the latest version of parse (1.14.2).

It seems that several solutions for my error have suggested making sure Xcode and the parse pod were up-to-date. Which they are. Another person said they had issues, even though the parse pod said it was updated, the old pod was still being used. I removed parse form my podfile, ran pod update and install, then reinserted parse in the podfile to run 'pod install', but same results.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //Set up Parse

    [Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
        configuration.applicationId = @"....";
        configuration.clientKey = @"....";
        configuration.server = @"https://parseapi.back4app.com";
    }]];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps others that have this or similar issues. I found that there was on old 'parse.framework' file in my workspace directory. Not sure if all these steps are necessary, but here is what I did...

1. Removed 'pod Parse' from podfile
2. Ran 'pod update' in terminal
3. Deleted remaining 'parse.framework' file
4. Re-added 'pod Parse' in podfile
5. Ran 'pod update' in terminal

Runs like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing parse.framework from your Xcode project, open up your finder and remove parse.framework from your app directory as Xcode default build settings will include your directory to search for frameworks.